# Instance Erasure by matching type "Any"?

Tags: scala

I'm aware that you can match type tags when you have two of them, but how do you accomplish this kind of thing when one of your objects is "Any" ? Is there some way to accomplish the (incorrect) code below? Keep in mind, the function "confirm" is designed to take type Any so it can remain flexible at run-time. Thank you

```
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

    object TestRun  extends App {


      class Matcher[T:TypeTag] {

        def confirm(x:Any):Boolean {       //I don't want to add paramaters to this, must remain Any
          val myTT = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
          x.isInstanceOf [myTT.tpe] // return an answer?  
        }


      }

      val m =new Matcher[Int]
//example of the output I would expect      
      m.confirm(44) //true
      m.confirm("test") //false

      val m2 =new Matcher[Seq[String]]
      m2.confirm(Seq("A","B","C") //true


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build on this:

```
def confirm(x: Any): Boolean = {
  val myTT = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
  println(x.getClass)
  println(myTT.mirror.runtimeClass(myTT.tpe))

  // Compiles, but only exact matches
  //x.getClass == myTT.mirror.runtimeClass(myTT.tpe)

  // Better, but not perfect
  myTT.mirror.runtimeClass(myTT.tpe).isAssignableFrom(x.getClass)
}
```

This works basically, but

- You have to add further code to handle int/java.lang.Integer et. al.
- You possibly have to add code to handle the element's type of a collection/container etc., because that type is erased, it it's therefore not considered in the comparison above.